# What does sitting at the right hand of someone mean with respect to authority? (Heb 1:3, Mt 20:23)

Tags: word-study, matthew, hebrews

What does sitting at the right hand of someone mean with respect to authority? ([Heb 1:3](https://biblehub.com/hebrews/1-3.htm), Mt 20:23)

It has been proposed that before the Word became flesh he had the authority of God because he was God. ([John 1:1](https://www.bibliatodo.com/en/the-bible/james-moffatt-new-testament/john-1)).

However we see post resurrection that the Son sits at the right hand of God (Hebrews 1:3) and that resurrected humans are to sit at his right hand.   He sits at the right hand hand of power (Matthew 26:64) and so is not the power himself.  Compare [1 Corinthians 11:3](https://biblehub.com/1_corinthians/11-3.htm) where the Father is his head post resurrection.

At [Matthew 20:23](https://biblehub.com/matthew/20-23.htm) Jesus will have resurrected humans sitting at his right hand.

What does sitting at the right hand of someone mean with respect to authority?

Comment: Sitting at the right hand of power usually means being endowed with that person's power, and acting as their right hand man.

Answer (score 3):

The Lord Jesus Christ at the right hand of the Father is a reference to Psa. 110:1 and 110:5.

First, in Psa. 110:1, Yahveh says to David’s lord (cf. Matt. 22:43–45), “Sit at My right hand...” Therefore, there is a lord (אָדוֹן) at Yahveh’s right hand. This could, of course, be just another human Davidic king.

#### On the Word אֲדֹנָי (*Adonai*) in Psa. 110:5

However, in Psa. 110:5, it states,

> <sup>5</sup> **Adonai** at Your right hand shall strike through kings in the day of his wrath.

Many English translations have “The Lord,” but to be clear, the Hebrew text has the word אֲדֹנָי (*Adonai*), which is essentially equivalent to the Tetragrammaton and almost always used in reference to Yahveh,<sup>1</sup> but **never** mere men.

Therefore, Psa. 110:1 and 110:5 are stating that Yahveh is at Yahveh’s right hand. When the New Testament alludes to these psalms by stating that the Lord Jesus Christ is at the right hand of the Father (Yahveh), it is indicating that the Lord Jesus Christ is the אֲדֹנָי of Psa. 110:5, and thus, Yahveh.

---

#### On the Word לַאדֹנִי (*laʿdoni*) in Psa. 110:1

The word לַאדֹנִי in Psa. 110:1 consists of a lamed prefix (“to”) and a 1st person, singular number, pronominal suffix (“my”). At the root is the word אָדוֹן (*adon*), “lord.”

It is asserted that אָדוֹן is never used in reference to Yahveh; therefore, David’s lord (“my lord”) in Psa. 110:1 could not also be God. Rather, David’s lord must be a mere man.

A cursory review of the usage of אָדוֹן in the Tanakh will demonstrate that אָדוֹן is in fact used in reference to Yahveh, countless times.<sup>2</sup>

According to HALOT,<sup>3</sup>

[image: HALOT, אָדוֹן, p. 13]

In fact, let us examine one particular passage, Mal. 3:1. Quoting the ESV:

> <sup>1</sup> “Behold, I send my messenger, and he will prepare the way before me. And **the Lord** (הָאָדוֹן) whom you seek will suddenly **come** to his temple; and **the messenger of the covenant** in whom you delight, behold, he **is coming**,” says the LORD of hosts. <sup>ESV, ©2016</sup>

Yahveh is speaking. Notice the parallelism:

“The Lord will come to his temple” :: “the messenger of the covenant is coming”

Most agree that the messenger of the covenant is the Messiah himself. Who is הָאָדוֹן (*ha-adon*), “the lord,” that will come to his temple? In the New Testament, this is the Messiah who came to the temple in the New Testament, and whose body, in fact, is the true Temple of God.

Notice how Mal. 3:1 states, “The lord whom you **seek**...” One verse earlier in Mal. 2:17, the people say, “**Where** is the God of judgment?” In other words, by asking where God was, they were seeking Him. Therefore, the lord whom you seek, who shall suddenly come to his temple, is identified as the God of judgment in Mal. 2:17.

Carl Friedrich Keil on Mal. 3:1,<sup>4</sup>

> הָאָדוֹן ist Gott; dies ergibt sich teils aus dem Kommen zu *seinem* Tempel d.i. dem Tempel Jahve’s, teils aus dem auf die Frage: wo ist der Gott des Gerichts? (2,17) zurückweisenden Relativsatze: welchen ihr suchet.
>
> Die Identität des Bundesengels mit dem „Herrn“ (הָאָדוֹן) wird durch den Parallelismus der Versglieder außer Zweifel gesetzt...
>
> הָאָדוֹן is God; this is evident partly from the coming to *His* temple, i.e., Yahveh’s temple, [and] partly from the relative clause “whom you seek” referring back to the question “Where is the God of judgment?” (Mal. 2:17).
>
> The identity of the angel (messenger) of the covenant with the “Lord” (הָאָדוֹן) is placed beyond doubt by the parallelism of the parts of the verse…

---

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> It appears that אֲדֹנָי is only used elsewhere to refer to angels in Gen. 18:3 and Gen. 19:18, although the interpretation of these passages is debated. Moreover, even if אֲדֹנָי in these verses referred to angels, it does not refer to men. It is only ever used in reference to supernatural beings.
<sup>2</sup> cf. Neh. 8:10, 10:29; Psa. 8:1, 8:9, 97:5, 114:7, 135:5, 136:3, 147:5; Isa. 1:24, 3:1, 10:16, 10:33, 51:22; Mic. 4:13; Zec. 4:14, 6:5; Mal. 3:1
<sup>3</sup> HALOT, p. 13
<sup>4</sup> Keil, p. [703](https://books.google.com/books?id=T3sj7RenPiUC&pg=PA703#v=onepage&q&f=false)

#### References

Keil, Carl Friedrich. [*Biblischer Commentar über das alte Testament. Dritter Teil: die prophetischen Bücher.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=T3sj7RenPiUC) Vierter Band: die zwölf kleinen Propheten. 2nd ed. Leipzig: Dörffling and Franke, 1873.

Koehler, Ludwig; Baumgartner, Walter. *A Hebrew and Aramaic Lexicon of the Old Testament.* Trans. Richardson, M. E. J. Ed. Baumgartner, Walter; Stamm, Johann Jakob. Leiden: Brill, 2002.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108907/discussion-on-answer-by-der-ubermensch-what-does-sitting-at-the-right-hand-of-so).

Comment: Does the word my lord/adoni in Psalm 110:1 refer to YHWH?

Answer (score 0):

> Exodus 15:6 Your right hand, O Lord, glorious in power, your right hand, O Lord, shatters the enemy.

The right hand of authority signifies his power to conquer.

> Luke 22:69 But from now on the Son of Man shall be seated at the right hand of the power of God.”
>
> Matthew 26:64 from now on you will see the Son of Man seated at the right hand of Power and coming on the clouds of heaven.
>
> Psalm 110:1 The Lord says to my Lord: “Sit at my right hand, until I make your enemies your footstool.”
>
> 1 Peter 3:22 Who has gone into heaven and is at the right hand of God, with angels, authorities, and powers having been subjected to him.

Jesus ascended to heaven, sits at the right hand of God, a favored position having the power to conquer.

Caiaphas' interpretation of "at the right hand of God" was even more serious than just having power, but being the power.

> Matthew 26:62-65 The high priest said to him, “I charge you under oath by the living God: Tell us if you are the Messiah, the Son of God.”
>
> 64“You have said so,” Jesus replied. “But I say to all of you: From now on you will see the Son of Man sitting at the right hand of the Mighty One and coming on the clouds of heaven.”
>
> 65Then the high priest tore his clothes and said, “He has spoken blasphemy! Why do we need any more witnesses? Look, now you have heard the blasphemy. 66What do you think?”
>
> “He is worthy of death,” they answered.

Even the right hand of a gentile king represents power.

> Isaiah 45:1 "This is what the LORD says to his anointed, to Cyrus, whose right hand I take hold of to subdue nations before him and to strip kings of their armor, to open doors before him so that gates will not be shut.